# writting to text file vs updating a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, fopen, crud

I would like to know if there is any way of measuring the overhead time difference, and resource consumption (*memory*)  between overwriting a file vs updating a mysql database. Lets just assume that I am updating one row, BUT with two statements. Meaning I would have have to fetch the database for a result first as:

`SELECT personName FROM emplyees WHERE id = 1`

then having fetched that name I would do update

`UPDATE employees SET personName = 'foo' WHERE personsName = '$queryResult'`

Now, all of that query over a simple file overwrite, as something like this

```
$file = 'personName.txt';
fwrite(fopen($file, 'w'), 'newName');
```

I am guessing of course, the overwriting the file takes less time and resource, but until-and-to-what extent? How much heaver should the file have to be to consider choosing the query for executing a similar task?

Just as a wild guess, I am thinking wrtting to a file will be 10 times faster than update the row, but if anyone has a better explanation and practical guides on how to obtain the accurate information, It would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: If you only have one employee, then a file probably is simpler, but if you have 100 employees and just want to retrieve one of them, or to update or delete any of them, then work out how much boilerplate code you'd need to do this. If you store data as an array in your file, then how efficiently can you find employees whose salary is more than $20000 a year, or who has leave booked for today

Comment: Well, maybe that was not a good example, specially because I will be applying more advanced approach of read/writing the file, which will be done in `SplFileObject()` so, that is not a problem, and I think I would have max about.. lets say, 10 employees, and will have to update 4 details about them. So, the `SplFileObject` gives me flexibility, but What I am worried about is, not being able to know the resource consumption and speed the script takes to execute. @MarkBaker

Comment: Even with SplFileObject, you're going to need to load the entire file into memory, or do a step-by-step write to update individual employee records - if ISAM files were supported, so that you could work with individual (indexed) data records from the file, this would be a lot easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective: Measure the time taken to update a string column in a MySQL table with single row versus overriting a file with the same string in the File System.

Consider whether you want time taken to connect to the mysql server and disconnect be included (I got a gut feeling they will take more time than the query itself)

```
...
$val = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$start = microtime(true);

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","user","pass","my_db");
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query("UPDATE employees SET personName= '$val'");
$mysqli->close();

echo "Time taken for MySQL: ".microtime(true)-$start."s";

$start = microtime(true);

$file = 'personName.txt';
$fpointer = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fpointer, $val);
fclose($fpointer);

echo "Time taken for FileSystem: ".microtime(true)-$start."s";
...
```

Let us know the results :)

Comment: Although you are right, but this has got nothing to do with security. This is just plain trivial text, that needs updating over time.

Comment: I have not mentioned anything about security. Could you please clarify whether you are looking into benchmarking MySQL vs File System? If no, then tell us more about what sort of data you are to store, how often are you going to write/read it, the expected size of it. If you are into benchmarking, could you tell what exactly you want to benchmark? How many nanoseconds it takes to override a single table with single row containing single column against writing a single word to a file? If so, first of all you have to drop PHP, as it is not for benchmarking.

Comment: It is about benchmarking, I guess, I should've mentioned that first. Consider as if, I was writing something on a file/database on each page refresh. Something as simple as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but, it will overwrite the existing data, be it inside a file/database

Comment: I have updated the answer, based on your requirements. I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Seems good. I guess, I had not paid attention to the fact, I could record and get an accurate time of the benchmark using `time()` Is there more accurate way to do this?

Comment: microseconds is as far as PHP can go. Honestly, knowing the 'speed' of PHP I see no reason of getting more precise time than microseconds ;-)

Comment: I guess, you are right. But, I meant in the context of getting general information, like memory consumption too.

Comment: To measure memory you can use function memory_get_usage. But in that case, I advice you putting MySQL and FileSystem tests as sepparate files, and output the memory usage on the beginning of a file, and the end of a file.

Comment: where were the results of this test ?
or shall i run it ?